# How to combine two JavaScript ternary operators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have two variables of type boolean. These are props for one of my React components:

wide: false,
  extraWide: false,

I'm then using these variables with styled components like so:

```
max-width: ${({ wide }) => (wide ? '602px' : '500px')};
max-width: ${({ extraWide }) => (extraWide ? '852px' : '500px')};
```

Is there a way to combine these two lines into one? (desired logic below)

```
if wide set to 602px
if extraWide set to 852px
else set to 500px
```

This is the best I've come up with so far. What are your thoughts?

```
max-width: ${({ wide, extraWide }) =>
  (wide && '602px') || (extraWide && '853px') || '500px'};
```

Comment: Sure, don't use a ternary.  You're creating a readability issue.

Comment: Every response to you has already touched on this, but readability is pretty important in code. Going back to code later, looking at a small, complex mess makes it much more difficult to understand (and change) later. Focus on function and readability. You can compress it for your releases later.

Comment: How about `max-width: ${({ wide, extraWide }) => 500 + wide * 102 + extraWide * 353};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly suggest not nesting ternaries, but if you *must*.

```
max-width: ${({ wide }, { extraWide }) => (wide ? '602px' : extraWide ? '852px': '500px')};
```

The logic after the `:` only happens if the conditional is false.

Comment: much better than what I had.. THanks

Comment: strongly agree with not nesting ternaries, however there are some applicable use cases to do so. see:
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/nested-ternaries-are-great-361bddd0f340

Comment: It's all applicable.  But from a point of view of the number of developers who strongly grasp nested ifs, or chained ifs if you want to follow the verbage of that article, vs the number that strongly grasp nested/chained ternaries, the number (imho) is most likely unbalanced towards if statements.  And given a work environment involving a team, you have to write with the other developers in mind.  @StevenStark

Comment: Also, *Using ternaries will make you a better developer.*  Lol, that's hugely opinionated from the article.  You can use ternaries all day long and be a terrible programmer.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, it definitely is, but it's always interesting to see both points of view. I still never nest mine, I prefer readability.